# RegEx match to remove from string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove `#!#` instances from string when there's not `#` before or after the instance.

For example...

`LoremImpsum#!#Dolor` => matches `#!#`

`Lorem #!#ASD##` => matches `#!#`

`Lorem #!##` => no match

`Lorem##!#` => no match

my code so far:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(formattedHtml, @"(?<!#)(#!#)(?!#)")
    formattedHtml = formattedHtml.Replace(match.Value, "");
```

But it seems to me that negative lookahead or lookbehind wont work.
Thanks.

Comment: Your regex [does what you need](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%23%29%28%23!%23%29%28%3f!%23%29&i=LoremImpsum%23!%23Dolor%0d%0aLorem+%23!%23ASD%23%23%0d%0aLorem+%23!%23%23%0d%0aLorem%23%23!%23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you code fails in places where there are multiple occurrences and only one of them was supposed to be replaced.

Your Regex does it was supposed to do. However, the problem was with the Replace code. Instead of following

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(formattedHtml, @"(?<!#)(#!#)(?!#)")
 formattedHtml = formattedHtml.Replace(match.Value, "");
```

You should use

```
formattedHtml = Regex.Replace(formattedHtml,@"(?<!#)(#!#)(?!#)","");
```

According to your initial code, if it finds a match, it would replace all the occurances in the string even if it has a preceeding/succeeding '#'

Comment: Man I feel like an idiot. I now understand what i did wrong... Thanks.